# Showing part of an article in html with correct handling not closed html tags

Tags: html

the problem is that I have a page on which there are displayed article headers. Each header contains image title and first for example 1000 characters of an article. The article content is stored in database as an HTML text.

The problem appears when I cut the content of an article (to display it in a header) in the middle of for example `<b>` tag :

```
this is my article, 1000 characters foo foo <b> here is bold ... [here I do the cut]
```

as a result rest of the page (with article headers) is bold as well. How do people cope with that ? I would like to display styled html description of each article.

thank You very much for help

Comment: How are you 'cutting' the article? PHP? Javascript? ASP?

Comment: It is done on the server side in this particular situation using ASP.net

Comment: Which language is used on server side?

Comment: On the server side the main language is c#

Comment: Is there no way to search for html tags server side and either remove them or close them?

Comment: I'm anticipating you will have to do what @CGeniusGo suggested.  Don't truncate your article within a tag, and close any open tags.  The latter will provoke issues with formatting.  From a performance perspective you would have to either parse the article client side, or cache the parsed article server side.  The latter is more difficult to manage, so I would suggest simply trimming to 1000 chars and doing the rest in javascript.

Comment: I've overlooked the fact that you could just strip out all the tags, but since you're displaying the first 1000 characters I'm assuming you're giving them more than just a preview and would like to include formatting.

Comment: Yes the problem is that I would like to include formatting, the question is is there any common solutioin for finding and closing all unclosed tags in the given html part :D

Comment: It looks like JQuery can help you close any open html tags. The only problem now is to make sure you're not cutting in the middle of a tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/mUFSv/

Comment: @Geoist I'm not familiar with that part of JQuery but is it not possible to close only formatting tags ie: strong,b,italics... This is of course assuming that there is no over all page format which hopefully there is not.

Comment: It seems that PHP has a similar function to close tags: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=425085.  I anticipate that ASP.NET has something like it as well, but I've not touched it in years.  Also, if the article contained a <div> or <table> and you didn't close it properly, that would stuff up the rest of your page.. correct?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. In a blog, I want to preview the last article posted and so I cut the article after 500 char and add [...] at the end of the text. The problem is that (trusted) user are authorised to use html in the articles they post and sometime there is a cut in the middle of a html tag. And so all the page is screwed up...